# Bundling React-native android release not picking up code changes

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, android-gradle-plugin

./gradlew assembleRelease is not bundling the code changes unless I 
   run a script :

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file 
   index.js --bundle-output 
   android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest 
   android/app/src/main/res
```

react.gradle is applied in app/build.gradle file

```
  project.ext.react = [
        entryFile: "index.js",
        jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
        bundleInDebug : false,
        bundleInRelease : true,
        root : "../.."
]
   apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"
```

my package.json file is as below :

```
 "dependencies": {
    "apisauce": "0.14.3",
    "appcenter": "1.12.0",
    "appcenter-analytics": "1.12.0",
    "appcenter-crashes": "1.12.0",
    "appcenter-push": "1.12.0",
    "create-react-class": "15.6.3",
    "fastlane": "0.1.0",
    "format-json": "1.0.3",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "3.0.0",
    "immutable": "4.0.0-rc.12",
    "immutable-sort": "0.1.0",
    "lodash": "4.17.10",
    "moment": "2.22.1",
    "native-base": "^2.12.1",
    "path": "0.12.7",
    "prop-types": "15.6.1",
    "querystringify": "2.0.0",
    "ramda": "0.25.0",
    "react": "16.6.3",
    "react-native": "0.58.3",
    "react-native-animatable": "1.2.4",
    "react-native-calendar-events": "1.5.0",
    "react-native-chooser": "1.7.0",
    "react-native-cli": "2.0.1",
    "react-native-collapsible": "0.11.3",
    "react-native-communications": "2.2.1",
    "react-native-config": "0.11.5",
    "react-native-datepicker": "1.7.2",
    "react-native-device-info": "0.21.5",
    "react-native-elements": "0.19.1",
    "react-native-image-picker": "0.26.10",
    "react-native-material-dropdown": "0.11.1",
    "react-native-modal-dropdown": "0.6.2",
    "react-native-modalbox": "^1.7.1",
    "react-native-path": "0.0.5",
    "react-native-picker": "4.3.7",
    "react-native-picker-select": "3.1.2",
    "react-native-radio-buttons": "1.0.0",
    "react-native-segmented-control-tab": "3.2.2",
    "react-native-simple-toast": "0.0.8",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "3.0.6",
    "react-native-swipeable": "0.6.0",
    "react-native-user-avatar": "1.0.3",
    "react-native-uuid": "1.4.9",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "4.6.0",
    "react-navigation": "1.5.8",
    "react-navigation-redux-helpers": "1.0.3",
    "react-redux": "5.0.7",
    "redux": "4.0.0",
    "redux-form": "7.3.0",
    "redux-form-submit-saga": "1.2.1",
    "redux-logger": "3.0.6",
    "redux-persist": "5.9.1",
    "redux-saga": "0.16.0",
    "reduxsauce": "1.0.0",
    "reselect": "3.0.1",
    "schedule": "0.4.0",
    "seamless-immutable": "7.1.4",
    "standard": "11.0.1",
    "to-sentence-case": "1.0.0",
    "uuid": "3.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@storybook/addon-storyshots": "3.4.7",
    "@storybook/addons": "3.4.7",
    "@storybook/channels": "3.4.7",
    "@storybook/react-native": "3.4.7",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "8.2.3",
    "babel-jest": "24.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-ignite-ignore-reactotron": "0.3.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "5.0.0",
    "enzyme": "3.3.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "1.1.1",
    "husky": "0.14.3",
    "ignite-animatable": "1.0.0",
    "ignite-ir-boilerplate": "2.3.1",
    "ignite-redux-persist": "1.1.0",
    "ignite-standard": "1.0.0",
    "ignite-vector-icons": "1.1.0",
    "jest": "24.0.0",
    "mockery": "2.1.0",
    "react-dom": "16.3.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.3",
    "reactotron-apisauce": "1.13.0",
    "reactotron-react-native": "1.14.0",
    "reactotron-redux": "1.13.0",
    "reactotron-redux-saga": "1.13.0",
    "snazzy": "7.1.1"
  },
  "standard": {
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "ignore": [
      "node_modules/**"
    ],
    "globals": [
      "describe",
      "test",
      "jest",
      "expect",
      "fetch",
      "navigator",
      "__DEV__",
      "XMLHttpRequest",
      "FormData",
      "React$Element"
    ]
  },
  "jest": {
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/Tests/**/*.js",
      "**/?(*.)(spec|test).js?(x)"
    ],
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/",
      "<rootDir>/Tests/Setup.js"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      ".+\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/Tests/Setup"
    ],
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "config": {
    "ghooks": {
      "pre-commit": "if [ -d 'ignite-base' ]; then cd ignite-base; fi; yarn run lint"
    }
  }
}
```

It is very tedious and error prone to run the script each time.Couldn't zero what I'm missing. I have another project which doesn’t have this problem